# What is the Query for Stopping a Transaction?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

ACID properties of Transaction Properties says that either full transaction occurs or nothing occurs. Lets say I want to stop a happening Transaction.
What is the query for stopping a Transaction before it successfully completed?